# Шахматная доска

Tags: python, алгоритм, структуры, структуры-данных

На шахматной доске 3x3 в клетке (A, 1) стоит голодный шахматный конь. Он хочет попасть в клетку (C, 3), где растет вкусная шахматная трава. Какое наименьшее количество ходов он должен для этого сделать?

Конь ходит 2 клетки вперед и 1 влево/вправо

Решение на Python

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Вопросы по студенческим заданиям нужно задавать с их попытками решения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3):

Ну вроде бы получается так:

```
print(4)
```

Comment: Спасибо брат!)))))))))